# Knockout.js Image Src - w3c compliance

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, w3c-validation

I have a number of  tags on my page where the image src is set by Knockout.js code :

```
<img itemprop="thumbnail" data-bind="attr:{src: ImageFile}" class="prodimg" alt="Some Alt Text" />
```

When I run the page through w3c compliance it comes back with :

```
Element img is missing required attribute src.
```

Fair enough - I did try a workaround of setting src="#" but that then caused another odd issue (my pages are Asp.net MVC) whereby my controller code was being called twice for each request (see [MVC controller is being called twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751138/mvc-controller-is-being-called-twice))

So what can I do to pass w3c compliance, but not have all my code execute twice?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have sorted this by just pointing my img src to a single pixel image, which is then overridden by my Knockout code - keeps the w3c validator happy also